What design principles are used to create pipelined divider in RTL?
I know about division using iterative processes like Newton Raphson and Gold-Schmidt. These are not pipelined.
What method or procedure then can be used to create a divider for fixed point maths? Input is 12 bits, signed. Required output is 12 bits wit 4 fractional bits.
I know that pipelined divider can take a lot of resource. However, I am not sure how exactly it is designed.

Search term: array divider.

Pipelined Newton Raphson in this FPGA implementation: https://www.techrxiv.org/doi/full/10.36227/techrxiv.20515320.v1

There's no reason that iterative algorithms can't be "unrolled" and pipelined.
The same thing can be done with ordinary long division.
The design approach I've used is to figure out what each internal iteration looks like, write a generate loop for that, and then I usually need to write some slightly modified code for the very first stage and very last stage to get the data into the form it needs to have for the module inputs and outputs.
For example, I have a module that does binary long division on two unsigned integers. The input data width, the quotient width and number of fractional bits in the quotient are all parameters. For a quotient of N bits, it generates N+1 stages, where the first stage checks for overflow, and the remaining stages each generate one quotient bit.

Of course, all of the major FPGA vendors have IP that will generate iterative and/or pipelined dividers for you. I wrote my own because I wanted a module that would be portable across all vendors, and also because I have found vendor documentation to often be somewhat lacking.

" I wanted a module that would be portable across all vendors" , I am in the same boat.

Do you remember how much logic resource it was to create the pipelined divider?

Sorry, no, not offhand.

Since there are different methods to do (binary) division, which method would take least area and give highest fmax when pipelined?
